# Collaboration when developing a Solana program

Tags: solana-program, development

What is the most seamless way of collaborating with other protocol devs on the same program?

Are there any best practices for handling Anchor params like file-paths, symlink and better keypair handling etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Top chad https://twitter.com/sol_idity has a really good answer of having these scripts in your package.json

```
    "build": "anchor build && ts-node scripts/add-missing-idl-types.ts",
    "deploy": "anchor deploy  --program-name program_name --provider.cluster $MAINNET_RPC --program-keypair target/deploy/program_name-keypair.json --provider.wallet target/deploy/program-authority.json",
    "write-buffer": "solana program write-buffer target/deploy/program_name.so -u $MAINNET_RPC -k target/deploy/program-authority.json",
    "set-buffer-authority": "solana program set-buffer-authority --new-buffer-authority BUFFER_AUTH_PUBKEY -u $MAINNET_RPC -k target/deploy/program-authority.json",
    "close-buffers": "solana program close --buffers -u $MAINNET_RPC -k target/deploy/program-authority.json",
    "test": "anchor test --provider.cluster $MAINNET_RPC --skip-deploy --skip-build --provider.wallet target/deploy/program-authority.json"
```

where $MAINNET_RPC is a bash variable

Answer (score 0):

I would say syncing the locally used keypairs.
deploy the keypair of the programs /target/deploy

add [programs.localnet] for testing.

Comment: hmm but still have the issue of different filepaths